# Laravel Model hasMany - getting too may results

Tags: laravel, model

I'm learning Laravel, so I'm quite new.

I have 2 Models: House and Translation.

My House Model:

```
use HasFactory;

protected  $guarded = ['id'];

public function trans(){
    return $this->hasMany(Translation::class);
}
```

}

My Translation Model:

```
function House(){
    return $this->belongsTo(House::class);
}
```

}

When I do in the controller something like ($id=2 e.g) :

```
$house  = House::find($id)::with('trans')->get();
```

I get a result with all houses (there are currently 2 in the DB).
When I just do the query "House::find($id)->get()" it works fine.

What part am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

::with('trans') returns completely new query and forgets everything about your ::find($id)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use load method.

```
$house = House::find($id);

$house->load('trans');
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is, `House::find($id)` is a method that returns the element by its primary key.
Then, the `::with('trans')` gets the result, sees the House class and starts creating a new query builder for the Model.
Finally, the `->get()` runs this new query and the end result is what is return for the `$house` value.

You have two options that will result to what you want to do.

First one is, to find the house entry and then load its relation

```
$house = House::find($id);
$house->load('trans');
```

The second option is this:

```
$house = House::where('id',$id)->with('trans')->first();
```

The second one is a query builder that results to the first element with id = $id,
and load its relation with translations.

You can check for more details in the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#collections). They have a very well-written documentation and the examples help a lot.